# Does gateway have a genmask?

Tags: route

The genmask column is for destination column in print from `route`, but the gateway column does not have a genmask column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The network mask (or prefix) defines the length of the subnet address in a routing table. Each entry in a routing table consists of subnet address and mask and the next-hop gateway.

Each next-hop gateway needs to be locally connected to the router in question, so a network mask is not required.